# Is the following scheme CCA secure? I purposed a scheme and I am not sure if it is CCA secure, if not, how can it be CCA secure?

Tags: encryption, aes, chosen-ciphertext-attack

Here is my idea:

Under the symmetric key encryption. Alice and Bob share the symmetric key K. Let `HASH` be a secure hash function and `Enc_k(message)` be the encryption message m by AES in the CBC mode with a random IV

First, Alice compute `c = Enc_k(message)`

Second, Alice compute `t = Hash(m)`

Third, Alice sends `(c, t)` to Bob

Fourth, Bob receive `(c, t)`, first verify if `Hash(c) = t`. If this is the case, Bob decrypts `c` using share K to output m.

Is this CCA secure? Why and why not? How can I improve this?

Comment: Deleting your post along with the answer is not the way to behave here, undeleted it.

Answer (score 3):

This scheme is not CCA secure because it is not even CPA secure. In fact, it is not CCA secure even if we would replace AES-CBC with a CCA secure scheme, to begin with. The issue is that the ciphertext includes a hash of the plaintext, which leaks lots of plaintext information.

Additionally, using a simple hash function as an integrity protection mechanism instead of a MAC is quite problematic. But even if you used a MAC instead of a hash function, this scheme is still not *generically* CCA secure. A MAC need not conceal information about the message that it is integrity-protecting.

Comment: Thank you, great answer i think